# QML - Creating a re-usable ListView header component

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I've got 3 list views on a single page and I want to create a single `ListView` header component that I can use with each list.

So I have a ListView:

```
            ListView {
                id: listOne
                spacing: 5
                header: headerComponent
                model: ListOneModel
            }
```

It references the following header component:

```
            Component {
                id: headerComponent

                Rectangle {
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    height: 50
                    Label {
                        text: "List One"
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                        elide: Label.ElideRight
                        width: ListView.view.width
                        padding: {
                            left: 14
                        }
                        background: Rectangle {
                            color: "red"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I make the header component re-usable so that when I connect the `ListView` to the header I can also pass in a different title?

I know I can change the header component and add a `titleText` property, like so:

```
            Component {
                id: headerComponent

                property string titleText: "My Title"

                Rectangle {
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    height: 50
                    Label {
                        text: titleText
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                        elide: Label.ElideRight
                        width: ListView.view.width
                        padding: {
                            left: 14
                        }
                        background: Rectangle {
                            color: "red"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But how do I specify the titleText' property when using the header component in my ListView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a property within each listview then access that property from within the Header component.

For example:-

```
ListView {
    id: listOne
    property string headertitle: "list one header"
    spacing: 5
    header: headerComponent
    model: ListOneModel
}

ListView {
    id: listTwo
    property string headertitle: "list two header"
    spacing: 5
    header: headerComponent
    model: ListTwoModel
}

ListView {
    id: listThree
    property string headertitle: "list three header"
    spacing: 5
    header: headerComponent
    model: ListThreeModel
}


Component {
    id: headerComponent

    Rectangle {
        width: ListView.view.width
        height: 50
        Label {
            text: ListView.view.headertitle
            font.pixelSize: 20
            elide: Label.ElideRight
            width: ListView.view.width
            padding: {
                left: 14
            }
            background: Rectangle {
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create new file call `ListHeader.qml` contains your header:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    property alias name: mylabel.text
    width: ListView.view.width
    height: 50
    Label {
        id: mylabel
        text: "List One"
        font.pixelSize: 20
        elide: Label.ElideRight
        width: parent.width
        padding: {
            left: 14
        }
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ListView {
    header: ListHeader{
        name: "ListOneNewName"
    }
}
```

QML docs about [importing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-directoryimports.html) and [custom types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html#accessible-attributes-of-custom-types).

Comment: Is it possible to put ListHeader.qml in a sub-directory, perhaps named components, and reference it that way? @Jiu

Comment: Yes, for folder `components`, Just `import "components"`